# Typescript Referencing generic T in function body

Tags: typescript

If I were to declare a type as a separate variable, such as:

```
type Foo =  <T>(x: T) => T
```

Then use it to define a function:

```
const foo:Foo = x => {
  let a = /*...*/
  /*...function execution...*/
  return a
}
```

How can I reference generic type `T` in the function body, such as to declare variable `a:T` ?

Comment: I am afraid, this may be the solution `const foo:Foo = <T>(x: T) => { ... }`

Comment: Since `T` isn't in scope in the function definition, you would have to declare it again in the function definition as Nishant suggests, or otherwise you can write `typeof x` as a substitute for `T`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot refer to this type argument in any way, because it's in type declaration. It's basically saying "You see, any function that is of type `Foo` is generic, you can pass a type argument to any function of this type, and its return type and arguments will depend on this type argument". This type argument `T` that you specify in `Foo` doesn't actually exist in any way, it's just there to signal to any caller of `Foo` that it can accept one.

Now you use this argument when you write the actual *implementation* of a function of type `Foo`. Like

```
type Foo = <T>(x: T) => T

const foo: Foo = <T>(x: T) => {
    let a: T = x
    return a
}
```

Or for example you could name it differently

```
type Foo = <T>(x: T) => T

const foo: Foo = <U>(x: U) => {
    let a: U = x
    return a
}
```

The `Foo` type doesn't enforce anything, it just says "this function has 1 type argument" and the function can call and use this argument however it wants. It's even free to ignore it completely

```
type Foo = <T>(x: T) => T

const foo: Foo = () => {
  return 5 as any
}
```

Again, as far as the caller of the function is concerned, `foo` accepts one type argument just because `foo` is an implementation of the `Foo` type, even if `foo` doesn't actually use it.

Or you could add an extra type argument that is optional and an optional variable of this type

```
type Foo = <T>(x: T) => T

const foo: Foo = <U, K = number>(x: U, y?: K) => {
    if(y) console.log(y)

    let a: U = x
    return a
}
```

And this is still valid, because whoever calls `foo` can look at the type definition and see "Ok, `Foo` accepts 1 type argument and 1 normal argument". If they now provide 1 type argument and 1 normal argument, it will still work because `foo` is fine working in such conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Just assign/copy/clone `x` to `a`:

```js
type Foo = <T>(x: T) => T

const foo: Foo = x => {
    let a = x
    /*...function execution...*/
    return a
}
```

I was trying to infer generic type:

```js
type Foo = <T>(x: T) => T

type ObtainGeneric<T extends (...args: any[]) => any> = T extends (u: infer U) => infer U1 ? U & U1 : never

const foo: Foo = x => {
    let a: ObtainGeneric<Foo> = null as ObtainGeneric<Foo>
    /*...function execution...*/
    return a
}

const result = foo(32)
```

But unsucessfull because TS infers `T` as `unknown` because `T` will be known an possible to infer only when smbd calls the function

I don't think it is possible/safe to do this in type scope.

Comment: How does that help? The question is about referencing `T` not `x`.

Comment: @Clashsoft Since `x` is of type `T`, the variable `a` will also be of type `T` in this code. The question is how to declare a variable of type `T`, which this code does, so it answers the question.

Comment: `How can I reference generic type T in the function body, such as to declare variable a:T ?` - the second part of the sentence looks like an example to me. Other people may stumble upon this question with the intention to do more than just declare a variable with the same type, so an answer should not just focus on an example given by the OP.

Comment: This is why OP can just ignore my answer or downvote it